# Горняк - это кто?

Tags: этимология, семантика

В очередной раз специалиста по горным этапам в многодневных велогонках назвали "горняком". Все бы ничего, жаргон и жаргон, но заставило задуматься, почему шахтеров, которые, понятно, "роют землю" так назвали.

Дальше термина "на-гор**а**" не продвинулся. Но и этот термин не совсем понятной этимологии.

Есть разумное объяснение всему?

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, само слово "горы" происходит от морфа со значением, объединяющим и горы и недра. Минеральные, так сказать, кладовые. Наши предки давным давно подметили, что полезные ископаемые (руда, камень) тяготеют к горной местности. А вот уголь туда попал заодно, поскольку тоже из шахты добывается. И "на-гора" - в значении "наверх" - тоже вторично. Так что тут скорее всего переосмысление.

Этимология

Происходит от праслав. *gora, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. гора (греч. ὄρος), горѣ (ἄνω), русск. гора, укр. гора́, болг. гора́ «лес», сербохорв. го̀ра (вин. п. го̏ру), словенск. góra, чешск. hora, польск. góra, в.-луж. hora, н.-луж. góra. Родственно др.-прусск. garian ср. р. «дерево», лит. girià, диал. gìrė «лес», др.-инд. giríṣ «гора», авест. gairi-, ср.-перс. gar, gīr, возм., также греч. гомер. βορέης, атт. βορέᾱς, βορρᾱς «северный ветер», алб. gur «камень». По мнению этимолога Мейе, исходной была основа на согласный. Ср. лит. nugarà «спина». От гора́ образовано горы́ч «юго-западный ветер», поволжск.; го́ры мн. «высокий правый берег Волги».

Comment: А что за морф такой? Я по Фасмеру не могу однозначно такое сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Горное дело — сфера человеческой деятельности, связанная с освоением и использованием недр Земли (определение из википедии). Горняками иногда называют людей, профессия которых связана с этой областью (учёные, геологоразведчики, добытчики; Горный институт в Петербурге). За шахтёрами такой штамп закрепился в советской прессе, включая спортивную (игроки команды "Шахтёр"). 
Ну а в велоспорте такой жаргон (из википедии же):

**Горняк**

*Легкий спортсмен, обладающий хорошим рывком в гору...  **Горняки** обладают худшим индивидуальным ходом, нежели **раздельщики**.*

Comment: Что общего у гор и недр?

Answer (score 0):

Первые шахты в России были в Уральских горах, где добывали руды различных металов. Видимо отсюда и наименование. Сами шахтеры горняком называют не абы кого, а специалиста по горнорудному делу.

Answer (score 0):

На гора обычно сочетается с выполненным объемом. Употребляется не просто для констатации факта добычи, а для указания нормы, объема, веса завершения по плану.
Горняк это сам рабочий. Он не обязательно шахтер. Это больше группа связанных с горными работами. Извлечением полезных ископаемых. Машинист экскаватора в карьере в принципе тоже горняк.