# Он бедняк/бедняг

Tags: орфография

В чём разница между омофонами *бедняк* и *бедняг*?

Comment: Я плюсую, хотя вопрос задан исключительно криво и не относится к ответам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово ***бедняк*** устарело, с пообным значением используется слово ***бедняга.***

(1) Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой
**-ак- и -як-**

**суффикс 1.** Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в именах существительных, которые обозначают: 1) животное по характерному признаку (пестряк, сизяк, третьяк и т.п.); 2) самца животного (гусак)

(2) Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой
**-аг-(а) и -яг-(а)**

**суффикс 1**. Словообразовательная единица, образующая имена существительные **общего рода,** которые обозначают лиц по их признакам или действиям - обычно с эмоциональной окраской сочувствия или с оттенком презрения (бедняга, бродяга, деляга, добряга, здоровяга, работяга, стиляга, хитряга и т.п.)

Comment: То есть можно и *есть много бедняк*, и *есть много бедняг*?

Comment: Много бедняков и много бедняг.  У Р. п. возможно нулевое окончание (бедняга – бедняг) и окончание ОВ (бедняк – бедняков).

Answer (score 1):

> В чём разница между омофонами *бедняк* и *бедняг*?

Разница — в падеже, числе и значении:

***бедняк*** — форма **им.** падежа **ед.** числа слова [**БЕДНЯК**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA&all=x),

***бедняг*** — форма **род.** падежа **мн.** числа слова [**БЕДНЯГА**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0).

Answer (score 0):

ЯК(АК) - суффикс признака **по характеру действия**, скорее всего выраженному отглагольным причастием или глаголом. Моряк - тот кто что-то делает в море, ну в море что делать можно? Плавать можно, плавающий в море. Рыбак - тот кто что-то делает с рыбой - ловит рыбу, рыбачащий. Пестряк - не потому, что пёстрый, а потому, что пестрит или пестрящий. Червяк - червь имеющие повадки червя, поступающий как червь, роется в земле. Так что по характерному признаку, но **действия**. Сорняк - засоряющий почву.

Отсюда и горняк - с одной стороны горнорабочий, с другой, тот кто ходит/ездит по горам. В вопросе про горняка было почему назвали горняком [горного велосипедиста](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424202/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE)?

из Ушакова:

> ГОРНЯ́К, горняка, муж. (разг.).
>
> 1. То же, что горнорабочий (профc.).
> 2. Горный инженер или студент Горного института. Было два путейца и один горняк.
> 3. **Лыжник** - **специалист в беге на лыжах по холмистым**, неровным местам; ант. **равнинник** (спорт.).

Почему в горах горняк, а на равнинах - равнинник, а не ровняк не могу сказать точно, может, потому что в горах нужно упираться и проявлять характер, а на равнине - нет, само получается.

Ивняк - ивовые заросли, заросший ивами...

А вот АГ(ЯГ) "с эмоциональной окраской сочувствия или с оттенком презрения" или временно усиление качеств - баффнутый на качество, то есть уже не чистое действие, а уход от него, отрицание.

Скромняга - обычно не скромный, а тут, внезапно, скромный. Зверюга - чрезмерно зверский. Стиляга - выражающий стиль, соответствующий стилю, но не являющийся стильным всегда, а только временно соответствие за счёт одежды, но очень стильный вот сейчас, манерный.

Не характерность - постоянное качество, постоянное действие, а манерность - временное, разовое положение, возможно, усиленное.

Бедняк - живущий в бедности.

Бедняга - тот, с кем случилось несчастье. Временный бедняк.

С кем не бывает, бедняга, но хорошо, что не бедняк!

ЯК>ЯГа

Comment: Интересно, интересно! Голос от меня. Люблю слушать ваши рассказики.

Comment: Но, сэр, почему вы даете ответы и не ставите автору значок "полезный вопрос"?)  Это было бы справедливо, разве нет?

Comment: @Sharon Меня смущает бедняг). Ну и вообще, ответ несколько шире, чем вопрос получается. Точнее совсем не про вопрос. А вопрос максимально неконкретный, и с явной ошибкой. Просто я думал, как обобщить всё, после случая с горняк, вот и обобщил.